# File OpenRead with Uri vs String

Tags: .net, xamarin, .net-core, avaloniaui

It is recommended to store file paths as Uri instead of string.

In practice, I get to the OpenRead method that requires a string and not an Uri.

```
System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath)
```

What's the right way to handle this? I'm planning for desktop and mobile support.

`filePath.ToString()` returns `file:///mypath/myfile.txt` and is not recognized by `OpenRead`

`filePath.LocalPath` returns the standard `C:\mypath\myfile.txt` but may not be supported by all devices.

So what's the right way to do it?

Comment: "It is recommended to store file paths as Uri instead of string."  Who recommends this?  If the paths do not need to be portable between different platforms, storing the full path is usually not a problem

Comment: VS code analyzers were recommending... wait, it was for Urls stored as strings that it gave warnings, not local file paths

Comment: Ah I know where I got the idea that this applied to paths too, Avalonia UI v11, with file picker handling, changed it to return Uri instead of String for cross-platform support.

Comment: To clarify: (1) You conclude that it was your misunderstanding, not a xamarin problem? (2) Are you programming in `AvaloniaUI`, only using `Xamarin` for its ability to run on iOS and Android (aka "Xamarin Native")? Therefore NOT using `Xamarin.Forms` for UI?